# Is there a way to show many R xaringan slides at the same time (like the PowerPoint slide sorter)

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

I am using the `xaringan` package to make slides for a new class and I would like to preview all the slides in a talk (really in several presentations at once to find/arrange slides).  In PowerPoint I would just use the "slide sorter" option and it would show many/all the slides at once.  Does anybody know a way to preview/show all the slides in a xaringan presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tile View from `xariganExtra` could help you: https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/#/tile-view.